# Can't add text to IHTMLDocument2 WebBrowser

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, wysiwyg, ihtmldocument2

I found a solution. This code is working:

```
    webBrowser.DocumentText = "<html><body></body></html>";
    doc = (IHTMLDocument2)webBrowser.Document.DomDocument;
    doc.designMode = "On";
    doc.write(text);
```

---

I use this code to create a editable WebBrowser:

```
private IHTMLDocument2 doc;

webBrowser.DocumentText = "<html><body></body></html>";
doc = webBrowser.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;
doc.designMode = "On";
webBrowser.DocumentText = text;
```

Commands like this one:

```
webBrowser.Document.ExecCommand("Bold", false, null);
```

are working, but I can't add or delete text. 
If I just use this code:

```
private IHTMLDocument2 doc;

webBrowser.DocumentText = "<html><body></body></html>";
doc = webBrowser.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;
doc.designMode = "On";
```

I can add and delete text.
What's wrong?

Comment: Please add some code showing how you attempt to _add or delete text_ and the received error message (if any).

Comment: I wan't the webbrowser to work like a wysiwyg editor. There is no add or delete text code.

Comment: The web browser displays a web page. I don't think it's possible to interactively edit that web page. At least not with the `WebBrowser` control. You could implement your own editor and pass the resulted web page to a `WebBrowser` but I would not recommend that.

Comment: I know that it is working. I actually can edit the text. I used this tutorial: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/48398-creating-a-wysiwyg-html-editor-in-c%23/